# Laravel 5 getting the hash of an uploaded image

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I upload an image and I am trying to get the hash of the image in a variable without saving the images.

```
foreach($request->only('photos') as $files){
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(is_file($file)) {
            $fname = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $hash = file_get_contents($fname));

            dd($hash);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

> "file_get_contents(1.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory"

Anyone knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the file contents of the filename alone, which does not include the path to the file.  You need to include the full path to the file:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file->path());
dd($content);
```

Note though that you are loading the actual file contents, not generating a hash.  If it is actually a hash you want, you could do something like:

```
$hash = md5_file($file->path());
```

Of course there are [other hashing options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

Comment: will this `$content` be a hash string or what exactly because I can't dd, this code happens in an ajax call

Comment: BTW if you are just debugging, you can `dd()` in an AJAX call and see the results.  Use your browser tools, click on the Network tab, and click on the AJAX request.  You will be able to see the request itself, including parameters, and the response.

Comment: Yeah I know but for some reason I don't see anything in my network tab when I select preview or response, but it's fine I tested otherwise and it seems to work so thank you :)